# usar funcion js de archivo externo dentro de componente angular 2/4/5

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, angular4, angular5

mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo 2 funciones en JavaScript

```
function checked(id) {
document.getElementById(id).checked = true;}


function unChecked(id) {
document.getElementById(id).checked = false;}
```

estas las uso para no poder checkear un checkbox sin que el anterior este checkeado, en angular 4 nosé como logre poder usar esas funciones dentro de los componentes, ahora me toco migrar a angular 5 y al querer utilizar esas funciones dentro de mi componente me da error, como puedo llamar funciones de un archivo js externo dentro de mi componente?

o como podría replicar esas funciones en un componente?

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Lo que intentas es un poco raro, en angular no sueles necesitar acceder al DOM directamente. Si añades el código de tu componente a la pregunta, seguramente podamos ayudarte a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si pones un ngModel en el check. Esa variable en tu componente tendrá el valor true o false, en función de si está seleccionado o no.

Es decir. Si tu en HTML pones:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="check.selected">
```

En tu component.ts de ese html esa variable check.selected será true cuando esté checkeado y false cuando quite el check. Recuerda inicializar dicha variable a false en tu component ya que si no lo haces será undefined hasta que se seleccione.